# MYSQL: output list with condition

Tags: mysql

I have this relational database with 3 tables:

Members table

```
id  member
1    Tina
2    John
3    Ellis
4    Dave
```

Projects Table

```
id   name     year
1    summer   2014
2    spring   2015
3    winter   2016
```

Subscribers table

```
id  members_id project_id
1     1           2
2     1           3
3     2           1
4     2           3
5     3           1
6     4           2
7     4           1
```

What I'm looking for is a MYSQL query that will output per member the latest project they have subscribed to. So the query will give this result:

```
member     name
 Tina      winter
 John      winter
 Ellis     summer
 Dave      spring
```

I have this query

```
SELECT members.member, projects.name
FROM members
JOIN subscribers ON members.id = subscribers.members_id
JOIN projects ON projects.id = subscribers.projects_id
```

But this gives me 7 rows with members and their respective projects name.
I want just the 4 members with  their latest project name as mentioned above.

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT `members`.`member`, `projects`.`name`
FROM `members`
  JOIN ( SELECT `members_id` , MAX(`project_id`) AS `project_id`
         FROM `subscribers` GROUP BY subscribers.`members_id`) AS `latest`
    ON `members`.`id` = `latest`.`members_id`
  JOIN `projects` ON `projects`.`id` = `latest`.`project_id`
ORDER BY `members`.`id`;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT members.member, projects.name
FROM members
JOIN (SELECT members_id, MAX(project_id) AS projects_id FROM 
      subscribers GROUP BY members_id) S
ON members.id = s.members_id
JOIN projects 
ON projects.id = s.projects_id
```

The above query will work under the assumption that, In `Project` table as `id` increase `Year` also increase (or do not decrease).

Comment: your query gives an error : "Unknown column 's.projects_id' in 'on clause' "

And indeed: Every new project will increase the year.

Comment: @Jojoseph `MAX(project_id) as projects_id`